# Get Daily sales from database - days without sales should show 0 - sales of last 30 days

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I need to create a graph of statistics for sales from the last 30 days. On some days there are no sales so I have to show 0 on these days.

**MySQL**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total, DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(tmstmp)) AS soldDay
FROM tl_voucher_create
WHERE sold = 1 
GROUP BY soldDay
ORDER BY tmstmp DESC 0,30
```

**PHP array of the result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [total] => 1
            [soldDay] => 24
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [total] => 1
            [soldDay] => 13
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [total] => 4
            [soldDay] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [total] => 2
            [soldDay] => 23
        )
```

Using a loop, I put the values into a new array:

```
for ($x = $day; $x < 31; $x++) {
    if (isset($this->_["soldDaily"][$x]["soldDay"])) {
        $total[$x] = $this->_["soldDaily"][$x]["total"];
    } else {
        $total[$x] = 0;
    }
}
```

How can I make the correct output with the values for the last 30 days, in the correct order?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base your query on the actual date:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total, DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(tmstmp)) AS sold_date
FROM tl_voucher_create
WHERE sold = 1
  AND sold_date BETWEEN DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY sold_date
ORDER BY sold_date DESC
```

Assuming the result from your query looks like this:

```
$data = [
    [
        'total' => 7,
        'sold_date' => '2017-02-28'
    ],
    [
        'total' => 19,
        'sold_date' => '2017-02-27'
    ],
    [
        'total' => 8,
        'sold_date' => '2017-02-24'
    ],
    [
        'total' => 5,
        'sold_date' => '2017-02-22'
    ],
    [
        'total' => 12,
        'sold_date' => '2017-02-21'
    ]
];
```

You now need to base your PHP on an actual date object rather than just a numeric 30-iteration loop, otherwise you will run into various problems and inaccuracies in your reporting because dates are not as simple as just looping from 1 to 30 (months have different numbers of days, you cannot easily cross back into the previous month, daylight savings issues, dates are different across timezones, etc.)

```
// Organise the array by date
$dates = [];
foreach ($data as $day) {
    $dates[$day['sold_date']] = $day['total'];
}

// Loop through the last 30 days and match each iteration with the data
$d = new DateTime();
for ($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++) {

    $date = $d->format('Y-m-d');

    // If there's no data for the specified date, use zero
    $total = isset($dates[$date]) ? $dates[$date] : 0;

    echo '<p>' . $total . ' sold on ' . $date . '</p>';

    $d->modify('-1 day');
}
```

Comment: great! THX a lot!!